# How to modify existing claims in JWT from Keycloak for OIDC flow?

Tags: jwt, keycloak, openid-connect, access-token, pyjwt

I'm generating JWTs for a service for authentication and we're using Keycloak as the OAuth server.

I've set up a realm R, a client C, and a user U. I setup a protocol mapper to include "C" in the "aud". I generated the JWTtoken for U and when I check the payload, I see `"aud": ["C", "account"]`. Which is great, I wanted `C` to be present. But I do not want `"account"` to be present in the `"aud"`.

How do I configure this in keycloak? Similarly, the scope reads - `"scope": "email profile test-client-rhs"` and I wish to remove `"email profile"` from it. I've been googling around a lot and trying out different stuff in Keycloak but I can't get this to work somehow.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I generated the JWTtoken for U and when I check the payload, I see
> "aud": ["C", "account"]. Which is great, I wanted C to be present. But
> I do not want "account" to be present in the "aud".

Instead of an audience Mapper you can use a `Hardcoded claim` Mapper with:

- `Token Claim Name` set to `aud`
- `Claim value` set to `C`
- `Add to access token` set to `ON`

this mapper will override the original claim `"aud": "account"` with `"aud": "C"`

Like so:

**(Old Keycloak UI)**

[image]

**(For the NEW Keycloak UI)**

- Go to the tab `Client Scopes`
- Click on the scope -dedicated (e.g., test-dedicated in my example)

[image]

- Click on `Configure a new mapper`

[image]

- Select `Hardcoded claim`, and then fill up
- Click on `Save`.

The client will be the client that you are using to authenticate against.

> How do I configure this in keycloak? Similarly, the scope reads -
> "scope": "email profile test-client-rhs" and I wish to remove "email
> profile" from it.

For this you need to go to:

- The realm where the client is
- Go to clients and select the client
- Click on the tab "Client Scopes"

**(For the Old Keycloak UI)**

- Remove the scopes `email` and `profile` from `"Assigned Default Client Scopes"`

like so:

[image]

**(For the NEW Keycloak UI)**

- change the scopes `email` and `profile` from `Default` to `Optional`, Like so:

[image]

Comment: This worked like a CHARM! Thank you so much!!

Comment: You are welcome, glad to hear that